# Random hash in Python

Tags: python, hash, md5

What is the **easiest** way to generate a random hash (MD5) in Python?

Comment: Random as in for anything? Or for an object?

If you just want a random MD5, just pick some numbers.

Comment: I am renaming files before uploading and want a filename like this: timestamp_randommd5.extension

Cheers!

Comment: You could just rename them to timestamp_randomnumber.ext. There really isn't a reason why md5(randomnumber) would be any better than randomnumber itself.

Comment: best answer for Python 3 is the last one `import uuid; uuid.uuid().hex` http://stackoverflow.com/a/20060712/3218806

Answer (score 179, accepted):

A md5-hash is just a 128-bit value, so if you want a random one:

```
import random

hash = random.getrandbits(128)

print("hash value: %032x" % hash)
```

I don't really see the point, though. Maybe you should elaborate why you need this...

Comment: +1 for not computing a relatively expensive hash from a random number: this approach is 5x faster.

Comment: +1 - surely this is better than my answer, can be used also like this: hex(random.getrandbits(128))[2:-1] this gives you same output as md5 hexdigest method.

Comment: the random.seed() call is useless, more or less.

Comment: I would've used os.urandom because wanting an MD5 hash might mean wanting a secure one.

Comment: Here's how to do it with `os.urandom`: `''.join('%02x' % ord(x) for x in os.urandom(16))`

Comment: hex(random.getrandbits(128))[2:-1] sometimes gives you a 31 characters long string (expected 32 all times).

Comment: my approach: ```f'{random.getrandbits(64):016x}'```

Answer (score 160):

I think what you are looking for is a universal unique identifier.Then the module UUID in python is what you are looking for.

```
import uuid
uuid.uuid4().hex
```

UUID4 gives you a random unique identifier that has the same length as a md5 sum. Hex will represent is as an hex string instead of returning a uuid object.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html

Answer (score 93):

The [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) was added in Python 3.6+. It provides cryptographically secure random values with a single call. The functions take an optional `nbytes` argument, default is 32 (bytes * 8 bits = 256-bit tokens). MD5 has 128-bit hashes, so provide 16 for "MD5-like" tokens.

```
>>> import secrets

>>> secrets.token_hex(nbytes=16)
'17adbcf543e851aa9216acc9d7206b96'

>>> secrets.token_urlsafe(16)
'X7NYIolv893DXLunTzeTIQ'

>>> secrets.token_bytes(128 // 8)
b'\x0b\xdcA\xc0.\x0e\x87\x9b`\x93\\Ev\x1a|u'
```

Answer (score 50):

This works for both python 2.x and 3.x

```
import os
import binascii
print(binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16)))
'4a4d443679ed46f7514ad6dbe3733c3d'
```

Comment: thanks. this is the best way to make a random hash key.

Comment: works for 2.x and 3.x: binascii.hexlify(os.urandom(16))

Answer (score 25):

Yet another approach. You won't have to format an int to get it.

```
import random
import string

def random_string(length):
    pool = string.letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(pool) for i in xrange(length))
```

Gives you flexibility on the length of the string.

```
>>> random_string(64)
'XTgDkdxHK7seEbNDDUim9gUBFiheRLRgg7HyP18j6BZU5Sa7AXiCHP1NEIxuL2s0'
```

Comment: I would probably change string.letters to 'abcdf' to reflect hexadecimal digits. But great solution!

Comment: `''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_letters + string.digits, 8))` more pythonic?

Comment: `string.ascii_letters` for python 3 instead of `string.letters`

Answer (score 6):

Another approach to this specific question:

```
import random, string

def random_md5like_hash():
    available_chars= string.hexdigits[:16]
    return ''.join(
        random.choice(available_chars)
        for dummy in xrange(32))
```

I'm not saying it's faster or preferable to any other answer; just that it's *another* approach :)

Answer (score 5):

```
import uuid
from md5 import md5

print md5(str(uuid.uuid4())).hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import os, hashlib
hashlib.md5(os.urandom(32)).hexdigest()
```

Comment: outputs something like: `eca224d7443ec56efd984c08904cbe4b`

Answer (score 4):

The most proper way is to use `random` module

```py
import random
format(random.getrandbits(128), 'x')
```

Using `secrets` is an overkill. It generates cryptographically strong randomness sacrifying performance.

All responses that suggest using UUID are intrinsically wrong because UUID (even UUID4) **are not totally random**. At least they include fixed version number that never changes.

```py
import uuid
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('8a107d39-bb30-4843-8607-ce9e480c8339')
>>> uuid.uuid4()
UUID('4ed324e8-08f9-4ea5-bc0c-8a9ad53e2df6')
```

All MD5s containing something other than `4` at 13th position from the left will be unreachable this way.

Comment: `os.urandom(128//8)` takes me 5x as long, or 0.25 microseconds longer to compute. If you care enough that you need to save 1 second every 4 million hashes you generate, you should get a faster RNG like PCG. If you think it will *ever* matter that your 'hashes' are unguessable/unpredictable, you should use a CSPRNG as it's trivially easy to [reconstruct the RNG state](https://github.com/eboda/mersenne-twister-recover) after using your call ~160 times.

Comment: I don't understand your MD5 comment. Please explain.

Comment: With UUID4 you will generate a string that always contains `4` at 13th position. It is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from hashlib import md5
plaintext = input('Enter the plaintext data to be hashed: ') # Must be a string, doesn't need to have utf-8 encoding
ciphertext = md5(plaintext.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
print(ciphertext)
```

It should also be noted that MD5 is a very weak hash function, also collisions have been found (two different plaintext values result in the same hash)
Just use a random value for `plaintext`.

Comment: Requiring user input doesn't help with the "easiest" aspect of the original question...

Comment: Did you check your code? It's missing a paren on line 3.