# Generating random strings for user authentication on server

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, authentication

I want to create unique string ids that will be used in a user management system. I want each user to have a string that allows them to access their own database on a server. I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45154700/6176585) that you can use the [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html#module-secrets) module to create random strings, but since I don't know anything about user management I'm not sure whether to trust the pseudo-random numbers that lie behind the secrets package.

**Question:** Is it safe to generate a string for each user like this

```
secrets.token_hex(nbytes = 50)
Out[8]: '24d72775ae86151c600b6a64cef7191e2a55271615894a0ad3b05671978add68a16ad2beb66fa87e66ccdcc442ef4e57e9a4'
```

and let them use that string to identify themselves to enter the database on my server? Is there a better way that is as quick?

Comment: By "hash" you just mean a *random string*? Hashing is something very specific, and you don't seem to be doing any of it here.

Comment: @deceze Thanks, I edited my question!

Comment: This question might be better suited for [Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).