# Generate Random Seed In Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-seed

Is there a way to generate random seed? something like this:

```
def random_seed(length)
```

output example:

```
3273650411015667511766
```

or is there a way to do both nums and letters?
output example:

```
ryf65s4d4s6df54s6y4fs6f5b4y6s4fy
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random hash in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976577/random-hash-in-python)

Comment: What do you mean by "seed"? It looks like what you want to ask is not what you are asking.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues while the question is poorly formulated, to my understanding it seems he wanted both random integers and strings so not really a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @RMPR there are a ton of different hashes in the answers to that question. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9816388/3343753), for example, looks pretty similar to the expected output the OP asked for. I guess you meant random `int`s and `string`s in the output. I am missing something?

Comment: If you look my answer, I wrote two methods, the first only for random `int`s and the second for random `int`s and `string`s and because of the former I think those two questions aren't the same.

Comment: OP, in case you aren't aware, "seed" usually refers to the *input* of an RNG. For some RNG implementations, it is possible to extract the seed from an existing RNG. Python's default RNG is a mersenne twister, which has some awkward problems if you try to use a human-sized seed. Other RNGs like PCG are better in a lot of ways (as long as you aren't doing crypto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`os.urandom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.urandom). It let's you specify the number of random bytes you want to generate. Of course you can convert / interpret these bytes as whatever you like (integers, chars, ...). For example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.urandom(16)
b'-\xca(\xd2\xf7 \xe3:\x8fj\x19#\xe0-\xb8X'
```

`os.urandom` will use the OS source of randomness (such as sensor values, etc). If you call [`random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) without arguments it will also fallback on OS randomness if available, otherwise the current system time.

Possible ways to interpret the bytes:

```
>>> int.from_bytes(os.urandom(16), 'big')
305697826269747251034239012950993064203
```

Comment: An additional processing is required or am I missing something ?

Comment: @RMPR Of course it is up to the user how to interpret those bytes (as numbers, chars, ...).

Answer (score 3):

For the integers:

```
import random 

def random_seed(length):
    random.seed()
    min = 10**(length-1)
    max = 9*min + (min-1)
    return random.randint(min, max)
```

For the strings, a naive approach may be:

```
import random

choices = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

def random_char(pos):
   return random.choice(choices)

def random_seed(length):
  l = [None]*length
  random.seed()
  return "".join(list(map(random_char, l)))
```

Beware, **this shouldn't be used for security purpose** you must rely on `os.urandom` instead.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work;

```py
import random
length=random.randint(1,30)
chars=[char for char in '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz']
print(chars)
seed=''
for i in range(length): seed=seed+random.choice(chars)
print(seed)
```